# Where is the relic in Jackie's house located?

Tags: the-darkness-2

In between levels, you play a little in Jackie's house, where you can talk to different characters.

The pause screen shows that there's a relic here

[image]

Where is it located?

Comment: Oh boy, I just found that and now I can't remember where exactly it was. It's a book, and the only relic that the Relic Hunter ability doesn't work on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

It's in Aunt Sarah's room, on a night stand that's on your left as you enter the room. As lunboks said in the comments, it a glowing book (it's not a shrine as are all the rest of the relics).